# Cant Update User Meta in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to update user meta **after** admin updated the user data/user profile, but I can't get it work

Here my code :

```
    <?php

    add_action('show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields');
    add_action('edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields');

    function extra_user_profile_fields($user)
    {
    $is_haloagen = esc_attr(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'is_haloagen', true));
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="is_haloagen"><?php _e("Apakah User Ini Member Haloagen?"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="is_haloagen" id="is_haloagen">
                    <option value="no" <?= $is_haloagen == 'no' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Tidak</option>
                    <option value="yes" <?= $is_haloagen == 'yes' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Ya</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');


function save_extra_user_profile_fields($user_id)
{
    if (empty($_POST['_wpnonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-user_' . $user_id)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

    $is_haloagen = isset($_POST['is_haloagen']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['is_haloagen']) : '';
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'is_haloagen', $is_haloagen); # << this is ok and the usermeta is updated

    if ($is_haloagen === 'yes') {
        # print_r('yes');exit; << if i open the comment, it print yes if $is_haloagen == 'yes', so it working right?
        # below this, all usermeta is not being updated
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'package_id', "2656079");
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'package_listings', '-1');
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'package_activation', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_had_free_package', 'yes');

        if ("2656079" != get_user_meta($user_id,  'package_id', true)) {
            error_log("error tidak sama package id!");
            wp_die(__('An error occurred', 'textdomain'));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

let me clear something, the usermeta with metakey *is_haloagen* is **successfully updated** but below it, is not being updated, I check the variable $is_haloagen, $user_id(just 1 user exist) and nothing coming to my mind why this piece of script is not working

i'm using wordpress 6.4.2 with php8.1